# Make WebAPI internal to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I need to make a web api internal to Azure cloud. What attributes or setting to make?

setup

1. I have two application deployed in azure cloud.
   1st is a frontend MVC5 application with UI.
   The 2nd is a WebAPI.
2. The user external to cloud can make calls only to 1st application. 
   The 1st application calls the 2nd appliction internal to cloud.
3. i don't what users external to cloud make calls to 2nd application.

How do i restrict it?

The 1st application is a website deployed in cloud. Second application is also a MVC5 website with only WebAPIs deployed in cloud.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Azure Web Sites don't support virtual networks yet, what you can do is configure IP restriction.

Place this section in your Web.config file and replace the IP address with the MVC5 address.

```
<security>
  <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">    <!-- block everybody, except those listed below -->     
    <add ipAddress="999.999.999.999" allowed="true"/>    <!-- allow requests from the MVC5 app -->
  </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

One caveat is that all Web Sites from the same Azure region are sharing the same IP address.  To get around this, you need to configure SSL as described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/05/05/how-to-get-a-static-ip-address-for-your-microsoft-azure-web-site.aspx

Comment: yes i agree with your solution but would have been more happy if there are a way to configure this per API.

Comment: Happy = waiting until Azure Web Sites support virtual networks ;-)